# golang profiling running production application without restart

Tags: go, profiling, pprof, heap-profiling

I have a running production golang application. It has memory leakage. Need to find the cause.

If I restart with `_ "net/http/pprof"` issue might not happen again. Because out of 4 servers only this server has this issue

I want to profile the running server. From web I read pprof needs restart of application.

How can I profile without restarting application??

Comment: You can't. However a profile rarely shows the source of a memory leak. Since the only thing you can really leak are goroutines, a stack trace is usually more productive

Comment: Thanks @JimB If that is the case I will try restart with pprof and hope I can debug the issue when it happens next time